# Javascript Regex: Test a string for a re-occurring pattern, fail the test should any pattern not match

Tags: javascript, regex

My String contains a re-occurring pattern anywhere from 0 to 100 times.

Pattern x 1 looks like this:  "40:0040"
Pattern x 2 looks like this:  "40:0040;50:0050"
Pattern x 3 looks like this:  "40:0040;50:0050;55.0055;" <<<-- FAIL THIS PATTERN

I've spend considerable time, but still unable to create the correct REGEX test... My latest attempt below:

```
var validPattern = /(\d*:\d{4};*)?/g;

if ( validPattern.test("40:0040;50:0050.55:0055;60:0060;70:0070;80:0080;90:0090;100:0100") ){
  alert("good");
} else {
  alert("bad");
}
```

Comment: Use `var validPattern = /^(?:\d+:\d{4}(?:;\d+:\d{4}){0,99})?$/;` if you really want to support 0 to 100 occurrences

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.  Works great, now I need to figure out why it works.

Comment: Just to clarify: the string like `40:0040;50:0050.55:0055;60:0060;70:0070;80:0080;90:0090;100:0100` is to fail, right?

Comment: That should be a fail.. Unexpected period '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var validPattern = /^(?:\d+:\d{4}(?:;\d+:\d{4}){0,99})?$/;
```

It is following the `^(?:BLOCK(?:;BLOCK){0,MAX_OCC-1})?$` "pattern".

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of the optional non-capturing group:

  - `\d+:\d{4}` - BLOCK pattern: 1+ digits, `:` and 4 digits
  - `(?:;\d+:\d{4}){0,99}` - 0 to 99 occurrences of `;` and the BLOCK pattern
- `)?` - end of the group, 1 or 0 occurrences is set with the `?` quantifier
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fz7StM/1).